Dash Python: Linking tabs through @callback
This question is an extension of the question linked below:
Dash Python: @Callback in Layout function not being called
I have a simple dataframe:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'Class2': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
)  

I have created a data extraction function that splits the data based on the position of the column.
data_extraction.py
def dataExtraction(arg1):

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Class1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'Class2': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})  # <-- or Import df from somewhere
    df = df[[f'Class{arg1}']]

    return df   

tab_page.py
import layout as lay
import data_extraction as de
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html, Dash
import dash

app = Dash()

dash.register_page(__name__, path='/tabs') 

def get_layout(position):
    df = de.dataExtraction(position)
    layout = lay.update_page(position, df)
    return layout

tab1_content = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody([get_layout(1)]),
    className="mt-1")

tab2_content = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody([get_layout(2)]),
    className="mt-2")

layout = html.Div(children = [dbc.Tabs([
    dbc.Tab(tab1_content, label="1",activeLabelClassName="text-success"),
    dbc.Tab(tab2_content, label="2",activeLabelClassName="text-success")])])
    
app.layout = [layout]

lay.create_callback(1)
lay.create_callback(2)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

layout.py
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
from dash import Dash, dash_table, State
import dash_daq as daq
import pandas as pd

def update_page_test(arg1, arg2):
    layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.H1(f'Class {arg1}'),
        daq.NumericInput(
            id=f'numericinput{arg1}',
            min=0,
            max=100,
            value=0, ), 
        html.Br(),
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id=f'tableTest{arg1}',
            data=arg2.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in arg2.columns]),

        dcc.Store(id=f'{arg1}mystore', data=arg2.to_dict('records'),
                  storage_type='memory'),
    ])

    return layout

def create_callback(i):

    @callback(
        Output(f'tableTest{i}', 'data'),
        Input(f'numericinput{i}', 'value'),
        State(f'tableTest{i}', 'data'),
        State(f'{i}mystore', 'data'),
    )
    def updateTableTest(x,data, Orig):
    
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        Orig = pd.DataFrame(Orig)

        if x > 0:

            print(f'Callback for class {i} works')

            data.iloc[:,1:] = Orig.iloc[:,1:]*x

            return data.to_dict('records')
        return Orig.to_dict('records')

    return updateTableTest

I want to construct a tab page that consists of a page with 3 tabs. Something like this:
...

total_content = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            html.Div([
                html.Div(id='table-placeholder', children=[])
            ], className='row')
        ]
    ),
    className="mt-3",
)


layout = html.Div(children = [

    dbc.Tabs(
    [
        dbc.Tab(tab1_content, label="1",activeLabelClassName="text-success"),
        dbc.Tab(tab2_content, label="2",activeLabelClassName="text-success"),
        dbc.Tab(total_content, label="total",activeLabelClassName="text-success"),

    ]
),

])

Question:
How would I be able to update the layout.py section so that the total tab updates with data from the sum of the other tabs and when the Numeric Input boxes are adjusted the total also updates?
For example if Tab 1: [1,2,3] Tab 2: [4,5,6] -> Total: [5,7,9]. If the numeric input box was set at 2 in Tab 1 the result will be Tab 1: [2,4,6] Tab 2: [4,5,6] -> Total: [6,9,12]
I was thinking of using another callback option that updates the Stored data in each tab and then outputting it in to the total tab but I am not sure how that would work. I have tried this and I have got stuck:
def update_store(i):
    @callback(
        Output(f'{i}mystore', 'data'),
        Input(f'tableTest{i}', 'data'),
    )
    def Update(data):
        print(f'Callback update store {i} works')
        print(data)
        return data
    return Update

def output_total(i):
    @callback(
        Output('table-placeholder', 'children'),
        State(f'{i}mystore', 'data'),
    )
    def create_total_table(data):
        print(f'Callback of create Total {i} works')
        return data
    return create_total_table


As mentioned above ensure that the store in the callback is updated when ever the numeric input is updated:
def update_store(i):
    @callback(
        Output(f'{i}mystore', 'data'),
        Input(f'tableTest{i}', 'data'),
    )
    def Update(data):
        print(f'Callback update store {i} works')
        return data
    return Update

I made some slight tweaks to the above. it is the stores that need to be inputted and the output id needs to be unique.
def update_total(i):
    @callback(
        Output(f'{i}table-placeholder', 'children'),
       [Input('1mystore', 'data')],
        [Input('2mystore', 'data')]
    )
    def update_total_table(tab1_data, tab2_data):
        print("Callback works")
        df_tab1 = pd.DataFrame(tab1_data)

        df_tab2 = pd.DataFrame(tab2_data)

        total_df = df_tab1.add(df_tab2, fill_value=0) # Sum columns from both tabs

        total_table = dash_table.DataTable(
            id='total-table',
            data=total_df.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in total_df.columns]
        )

        return total_table
    return update_total_table

In tab_page.py
...

total_content = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            html.Div([
                html.Div(id='1table-placeholder', children=[])
            ], className='row')
        ]
    ),
    className="mt-3",
)


layout = html.Div(children = [

    dbc.Tabs(
    [
        dbc.Tab(tab1_content, label="1",activeLabelClassName="text-success"),
        dbc.Tab(tab2_content, label="2",activeLabelClassName="text-success"),
        dbc.Tab(total_content, label="total",activeLabelClassName="text-success"),
    ]
),
])

lay.update_total(1)


Here's my approach:

Ensure create_callback Functionality: Make sure your create_callback function is correctly updating the stored data (dcc.Store) whenever a Numeric Input value changes.

Add a Callback for the "Total" Tab: Add a new callback that listens to changes in the stored data of both Tabs 1,2. This callback will sum the data and update the DataTable in the "Total" tab.


This is the modified code for your layout.py:
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash_extensions.enrich import DashProxy, Input, Output, State

app = DashProxy(__name__)

# Other parts

def update_total():
    @callback(
        Output('table-placeholder', 'children'),
        [Input(f'{i}mystore', 'data') for i in range(1, 3)], 
        [State(f'tableTest{i}', 'data') for i in range(1, 3)]
    )
    def update_total_table(tab1_data, tab2_data):
        df_tab1 = pd.DataFrame(tab1_data)
        df_tab2 = pd.DataFrame(tab2_data)

        total_df = df_tab1.add(df_tab2, fill_value=0) # Sum columns from both tabs

        total_table = dash_table.DataTable(
            id='total-table',
            data=total_df.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in total_df.columns]
        )

        return total_table

update_total()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


Thank you i think we are almost there. I have kept the update_store callback which is updating the store by using print data as a check. I am still getting an issue when using the update_total callback. It is not activating when i run the code and i just get a blank screen. As there is a for loop here would that not produce 4 inputs into the 'update_total_table' not 2?

Would this approach be better adding the updated store data from each tab? [State('1mystore', 'data')],
[State('2mystore', 'data')]

Actual don't worry solved it.
